# Upload image from string

Tags: image, forms, upload

If i have a filename for a local file on the computer:

$img = "deskfile:///D%3A%2FSCANS%2F%23AUKT%2Fimg2014%2F2014-06+SP%2FEPSON007.jpg"

how can i upload it the server without using the "file selector"?

If i enter the file adresses in the url window of a browser i can display the image.

But if i load the image in  tag they won't display. I've read it's becuse of restrictions in the browser.

I can't add a value caluse to the  either.

Is there anyway to upload the image from the string?

Or can i at least open the correct directory in the "file selector" so the user wont have the browse the whole computer when looking for the file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way.  You can use the File API with Html5 and/or a polyfill for this to load the image in the browser before posting it back to the server.  The best such polyfill that I know of is called Moxy/[Plupload](http://plupload.com/).  It includes Flash and Silverlight fallbacks for older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can display the image because it is stored locally in your computer. How do you know where is the image going to be in the user's computer. The only way to access the user's file system is through the file selector, once the user has selected a file you can then use any API to save that file in the server on your terms, but you will not be able to see each of your users file system from you page (security reasons). Could you elaborate more in what you are trying to accomplish? What exactly are you trying to do?